# Javafx.controls not found with PowerShell

Tags: java, powershell, javafx

I am using Eclipse and PowerShell. I have exported a java project into a runnable JAR ( test13.05.jar ) with Eclipse, and I want to open it from PowerShell. This project uses javafx, so I have copied the javafx-sdk-17.0.2 file into the folder that contains my project.
Then, I went into this folder with PowerShell, and typed
`java -jar test13.05.jar --module-path javafx-sdk-17.0.2\src --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`

Which has this result:

> Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

So I have tried running it without specifying the name:
`java -jar --module-path javafx-sdk-17.0.2\src --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`

And this time Powershell says:

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
> java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found

I have then tried the same thing, but I unzipped the src folder. It still has the same result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The module path is wrong; it should be a `lib` folder, probably under `javafx-sdk-17.0.2`.

Comment: Thank you! I did not think to see what was in the lib folder, but now that I've done it, I wrote : ```java -jar test13.05.jar --module-path javafx-sdk-17.0.2\lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml``` and the result was still      ``` Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application ```   Do you know what to do?

Answer (score 3):

The format for executing a JAR is:

```
java [VM args...] -jar <jar-file> [args...]
```

Where `[VM args...]` is an optional list of *VM<sup>1</sup> arguments* (such as `--module-path`) that configure the VM, and `[args...]` is an optional list of *application arguments* which are passed to the `main` method of your application. You have VM arguments in the application arguments section.

Also, as [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72276882/javafx-controls-not-found-with-powershell#comment127692759_72276882) by [James_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189127/james-d):

> The module path is wrong; it should be a `lib` folder, probably under `javafx-sdk-17.0.2`

The following might work for you:

```
java --module-path javafx-sdk-17.0.2\lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar test13.05.jar
```

Though I'm still not sure if `javafx-sdk-17.0.2\lib` will work, unless the `javafx-sdk-17.0.2` directory is in the current working directory. If you still get the same error, replace `javafx-sdk-17.0.2\lib` with the absolute path to the directory (if there are spaces in the path then surround the path with quotes).

---

<sup>1. "VM" is an abbreviation for "virtual machine". As in, the Java Virtual Machine.</sup>